# Cannot convert ‘float****’ to ‘float (*)[128][3][4]’ in initialization

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have the following 2 typedef's:

```c
typedef float matrix_3x4[3][4];
typedef matrix_3x4 bone_mat[128];
```

And the following function definition:

```c
float ****get_bones();
```

Why is the following code giving me a type conversion error?

```c
bone_mat *mat = get_bones();
```

Error:

```
error: cannot convert ‘float ****’ to ‘float (*)[128][3][4]’ in initialization
   85 |     bone_mat *mat = get_bones();
      |                     ~~~~~~~~~^~
      |                              |
      |                              float****
```

Tried changing the type of `mat` to `bone_mat` or `bone_mat**`, but shouldn't `float(*)[128][3][4]` be the same as `float****`?

Casting the return value of the function to `(bone_mat*)` doesn't work either.

Comment: Not an answer, but once you get beyond more than 2 levels of indirection, consider changing your types to nested structures and arrays thereof.  It's hard to reason about a `float ****`.

Comment: Important note: ARRAYS ARE NOT POINTERS.

Comment: @pmacfarlane In this case, I did not make the `get_bones()` function.

Comment: It may be surprising but `float****` is **not** a 4d array.

Comment: @tstanisl But can't it act as a pointer to a 3d one?

Comment: No. Because dimensions of an array object are a bound its type. The `float****` has no dimensions information in it thus it is not a pointer to array even though it admits `ptr[a][b][c][d]` syntax

Comment: @tstanisl Think about the memory and addresses involved. `float*** *` is a pointer to a `float***`. That means that when you dereference a `float****`, you arrive at a location in memory that contains a `float***`. Not a `float`, but a pointer to another pointer. Dereference that pointer, and you arrive a location that contains a `float**`, Still not a float, but another pointer to a pointer. I could keep going. Contrast that with `float (*)[128][3][4]`, which is a pointer to a chunk of memory with `128*3*4` contiguous floats.

Comment: @trxgnyp1 Do you have access to the source code of `get_bones()`?  If so, can you post it?

Comment: @Brian61354270 Your comment was probably the best explanation. I am marking the only answer as completed, but your comment is way better. The problem here is that I don't have the source code of the `get_bones()` function, and I actually know that it's supposed to return a `bone_mat*`, despite the definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pointer is **not** an array. A pointer can point to an element of an array.  `float ****` is a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to `float`, a very unlikely object to come across in a real life project.

`mat` is a pointer to a `bone_mat` which itself is an array or 128 arrays of 3 arrays of 4 floats, a very different type of beast.

Should you post the source code to `get_bones()`, I would be surprised if it returns an actual `float ****`, I would bet it allocates memory for a `bone_mat` and converts the object pointer to a type inconsistent with the allocation size and block usage.

Quoting *Brian61354270*:

Think about the memory and addresses involved. `float*** *` is a pointer to a `float***`. That means that when you dereference a `float****`, you arrive at a location in memory that contains a `float***`. Not a `float`, but a pointer to another pointer. Dereference that pointer, and you arrive to a location that contains a `float**`, Still not a `float`, but another pointer to a pointer. I could keep going. Contrast that with `float (*)[128][3][4]`, which is a pointer to a chunk of memory with 128 * 3 * 4 contiguous floats.

Comment: I do not have the source code of the function, only the definition. I am marking the answer as valid, but Brian61354270's comment explained way better.